# How to compile an executable using clang and safe-stack flag

Tags: c, linker, clang, llvm

I am trying to compile a simple hello-world executable using clang-3.7 (also tried 3.8 (dev)) with -fsanitize=safe-stack flag. As explained here (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/SafeStack.html), I need to pass this flag to compiler and linker.

*"To enable SafeStack, just pass -fsanitize=safe-stack flag to both compile and link command lines."*

I tried the following command to compile an executable:

```
clang-3.7 -fsanitize=safe-stack -o a.out -Wl,-fsanitize=safe-stack test.c
```

But the linker tells me, that i need to compile it as a shared library (-shared), if I pass the -f flag to the linker.

```
/usr/bin/ld: -f may not be used without -shared
```

How can I compile an **executable** using the -fsanitize=safe-stack flag?

Comment: Have you tried removing "-Wl,-fsanitize=safe-stack"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "pass it to both the compile and link command lines" the documentation means to pass it both when you're compiling, and when you're linking. It does not mean to use `-Wl`, which passes it straight through to the linker - `-f` means something entirely unrelated to the linker.

In this case,

```
clang-3.7 -fsanitize=safe-stack -o a.out test.c
```

is sufficient. If you were using separate command executions to compile and link, you would need to pass it on both:

```
clang-3.7 -fsanitize=safe-stack -c -o test.o test.c
clang-3.7 -fsanitize=safe-stack -o a.out test.o
```